# Why I read many response packet in every goroutine when I send a tcp shake packet(SYN) in many goroutines

Tags: sockets, go, networking, tcp

I'm building a port scanner to check if some TCP port at remote machine is open.

To improve performance, I just build and send a TCP SYN packet to remote port instead of doing full 3-way handshake.And if I receive SYN-ACK packet successfully,then that port will be considered as open.

Here is a part of my code:

```
conn, _:= net.Dial("ip4:tcp", target)
tcpSynPacket := BuildTcpSynPacket() // here I build a tcp syn packet
conn.Write(tcpSynPacket.Marshal())
deadlineTime := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
defer deadlineTime.Stop()
for {
    select {
case <-deadlineTime.C:
    return nil
default:
        bytes := make([]byte, 128)
        conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Millisecond * 200))
        readnum, err := conn.Read(bytes)
        responsePacket := parstTCPHeader(bytes[:readnum])
        matched := CHECK_IF_RESPONSE_MATCH_REQUEST(tcpSynPacket,responsePacket) // here I'll check if ack-no,src-port,dest-port in tcpSynPacket match seq-no,dest-port,src-port in response packet
        if !matched {
            // unmatched packets,may response for another routine
            continue
        }
        if responsePacket.rst_flg == 1 {
            // the port would be consider as close
            // build func return struct,and return
            ....
        }else {
            // the port would be consider as open
            // build func return struct,and return
            ....
        }
}
```

There are not for loop and CHECK_IF_RESPONSE_MATCH_REQUEST statement at old code.But when I do stress test, I found it's necessary.

Let's say we'll test if port 80 is open at 66.220.146.94.I open 1000 goroutines to call above code.

```
goroutine1: ack-no=11111

goroutine2: ack-no=22222

goroutine2: ack-no=33333

...
```

Then I found that in every goroutine,the following statement

```
readnum, err := conn.Read(bytes)
responsePacket := parstTCPHeader(bytes[:readnum])
```

will read all response packet even the read packet do not match the syn packet sent at current goroutine.

For example, at goroutine1, I sent syn packet(ack-no=11111),and read from conn. Then I found the seq-no in read packet could be 11112,22223,33334...
So I add a loop and some check logic at CHECK_IF_RESPONSE_MATCH_REQUEST.

But the loop read and check logic make cpu so high.

Here is a test result(I run it every 60 seconds)

[image: cpu%-runseconds]

Top 10 cpu cost using 3-way shakehand when open 1000 goroutine(Duration: 60s, Total samples = 780ms ( 1.30%)):

[image: flame graph(3-way shakehand port scan)]

Top 10 cpu cost using tcp syn port scan when open 1000 goroutine(Duration: 60s, Total samples = 30.51s (50.85%)):

[image: flame graph(tcp syn port scan)]

What I want to know is that:

1.Why conn.Read(bytes) read all response packets in every goroutine?Is net.Dial("ip4:tcp", targetip) correct?

2.Is there a lower-cost way to do periodic port scan(every 60 seconds) without doing 3-way shakehand

Comment: Unrelevant, but for avoiding angry calls from system administrators, I recommend to send RST, when you get SYN-ACK from some port. See: 'SYN flood attack'.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Sending RST seems has been auto done by OS when OS get SYN-ACK.  It does at Windows(check by wireshark) and some Linux machine. I'm not sure if all OS do this automatically

Comment: It seems that `net.Dial("ip4:tcp", target)` will create a row socket. And it will return all packets(any source port) from target ip when read from the raw socket, which make cpu run high I think

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

1. close `conn` at the end of the routine. `net.Dial("ip4:tcp", targetip)` is correct
2. reuse local ephemeral port in the socket pairs `local:port remote:port` when you craft the syn packet

Notes on 1:

Closing `conn` might not be the best idea, should do `2` above for these benefits:

1. not wasting cpu time for closing local ports
2. when you make multiple conns to the same addr too quickly and let kernel assign local port, the kernel ip stack might actually **plays up** - for more details, digging in this keyword `TCP simultaneous connect`

Comment: I do close `conn` before function call return, sorry for forgetting showing at the sample code.

Comment: For answer 2, I don't really understand.  

Even I reuse local ephemeral port, I'll still run into same problem when I scan port from 1 to 1000 instead of just scanning one port 1000 times.  

I think `conn.Read(bytes)` in loop is the root cause, it return so many packets from targetip that I have to filter match packet from 1000 packets(even more when concurrent is more) in loop.  

I wonder if there is a function can read tcp according some filter, something like:  

`conn.SetFilter("targetport=12345,ackno=23563324")  
`conn.Read(bytes)`